# React.js - Is there a way to grab props.match.params value before the render() method?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Post class which will dynamically display content from each post from the database depending on the params. My issue is that I want to use state, but the only time the match.params id value is available is during the render method - at which point I can't use set state because of infinite loops. As a work around I'm using local variables and only setting them in render if match.params is not null. But I ideally want to use state.

Is there a way to grab that param before the render method so i can use set state?

**UPDATED TO SHOW CODE:**

This bit is here is where I check to see the param and match it with the post from db:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.props.match) {
      post = this.props.data.posts.find(post => post.id == this.props.match.params.id );
  }
}
```

Because match.params is only available at this stage, I can't do it when the component first loads as it would be null.

In that post object I have a comments object, and again I would like to assign but can't. So what I'm having to do is assign it to state when I make a POST request (thus a method and not render):

```
postComment = (e, postId, postComments) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        let data = {
            comment: this.state.comment,
            post_id: postId
        }

        if(this.state.comment != "") {
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post_comments', data)
            .then(response => {
                // handle success
                console.log(response);

                postComments.unshift(response.data);

                this.setState({
                    comments: postComments
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
            });
        }
```

This means that to display the comments, I then have to compare state with the comments object in post. If state is bigger than the other, i.e. a new value has been entered, map that one, else map the other otherwise existing comments won't get displayed:

```
{
   this.state.comments > post.comments ?
   this.state.comments.map(comment =>
        <p key={comment.id}>{comment.comment}</p>
   )
   :
   post.comments.map(comment =>
         <p key={comment.id}>{comment.comment}</p>
   )
}
```

It just feels a bit messy and working with one array in state would be cleaner.

```
this.state.props.match:

{path: "/blog/:id(\d+)", url: "/blog/2", isExact: true, params: {…}}
isExact: true
params: {id: "2"}
path: "/blog/:id(\d+)"
url: "/blog/2"}
```

So when clicking on post 2 (blog/2), the above will print, when clicking on 3, id would be 3 and so on

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to properly help you, please provide a [mcve]. Cheers!

Comment: @claud.io updated to show code

Comment: what is `this.state.props.match`

Comment: this.state.props.match is an object containing the id of the post (taken from the URL). I've updated to show this object

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i had something similar to your problem. In general if your state depends on props, you can try to use getDerivedStateFromProps.

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    post = props.data.posts.find(post => post.id == props.match.params.id );
    if (post !== state.post) {
      //add your magic here
      return {
        //return a new state....this is like calling setState
      };
    }
    return null; // do nothing
  }
```

Comment: "Cannot read property 'params' of null" - this doesn't solve the problem that match isn't available until AFTER render(). I'm assuming getDerivedStateFromProps() gets run before render() in which case params.id will never be found at that point.

Comment: State depending on props isn't the issue here, I have a componentWillRecieveProps for that. It's the fact I'm relying on a url params id which isn't available until after rendering the DOM

Comment: i've seen now that match is in state...but anyway your question is kinda confusing. I don't understand how you are getting props.matche and why your stuff is not ready untill render.....